# How to get some simple data by Internet in Android

Tags: android, server

I need to get some simple data (actual currency values) to my android application. I'm not sure what is the best way to achieve it. Do I have to make some database and put it on server and than update it manually or there is some better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an API Service and access to this service from you android device. You donot need to do a server implementation for this.

e.g. for exchange rates check https://openexchangerates.org/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I decided to use values from European Central Bank. It works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Please make a server and a PHP which going to print out the values in JSON. You can validate your json with http://jsonlint.com/. After it you can download and parse the json with yourself or a 3rd part library (like retrofit).

You can use this website to generate POJO, so retrofit can parse the json for you by it`s own. 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
select: JSON instead of scheme and select GSON instead of JSON, if you are using retrofit.

sources:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson
https://github.com/square/retrofit
http://blog.robinchutaux.com/blog/a-smart-way-to-use-retrofit/